# Fedora 34: Pasting multiple commands into a bash terminal behavior change

Tags: bash, fedora

I use Mediawiki to store all the commands I need to do to rebuild my system from scratch when a Fedora upgrade is available.

Until now, I would simply copy/paste a huge set of commands into a terminal window and let it run free.

I am trying to upgrade my Fedora 32 to 34 and this no longer works.  When anything in my script enters a CLI - like mysql or even a new bash shell, execution stops until I type 'exit'.  Then, the SQL commands or whatever are executed in bash and makes an ugly display.

Here is the most simplified example of this that I could create.  This works fine in Fedora 32 but gets stuck in Fedora 34:

```
echo 'AAA'
echo 'AAA'
echo 'AAA'
bash
echo 'BBB'
echo 'BBB'
echo 'BBB'
```

I am guessing something changed within Fedora, I just do not know what.  I have searched and can't seem to find an answer.

My question is - what do I need to change so that I can get the old (F32) behavior back?

Comment: What version of bash comes with Fedora 34?

Comment: GNU bash, version 5.1.0(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: I'd expect the script to stop at `bash` and wait for you to type something in. Are you feeding the script something on `stdin`? If so, include a little of that so we can test it.

Comment: There is an example in my question.  Just copy/paste it into a terminal and you'll be able to reproduce it.

Comment: @JohnW The example in the question would stop at `bash` if I don't feed it anything.

Comment: @oguzismail If it's readline, do you think `export TERM=dumb` or similar could help? (I have bash 5.017 myself and can't reproduce)

Comment: @TedLyngmo - Yes - that is the problem.  That example does not stop in Fedora 32

Comment: @JohnW What do you feed the script in fedora 32? Nothing? And it just executes `bash` and exits?

Comment: Tangentially, regardless of this bug, the sane thing to do would be to store the commands in a script file and just run it from the prompt, or `source` it if it contains stuff which needs to be evaluated in your current shell.

Comment: @Ted no idea :/

Comment: @TedLyngmo - I can run the same exact example script.  In F32, it runs to the end. In F34, it stops at the bash command and I have to enter the word exit for it to continue.

Comment: @oguzismail - thanks - I might end up reporting this.  Have a feeling though it is something simple.

Comment: @JohnW ... but, if you run the script in the question in interactive mode, why would it _not_ start a shell and wait for your input when it comes to the `bash` line? What happens if you just type `bash` on the command line in Fedora 32? Doesn't it start a new shell?

Comment: @TedLyngmo - My Fedora 32 uses `GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` If you have access to that, you can see the behavior I have seen for years.

Comment: My Fedora 33 has exactly the same bash version - and starts a new shell at the `bash` line in your script.

Comment: Thanks Ted let me clarify.  I paste the commands into a terminal window.  On fedora 32 it executes the first 3 commands, opens a new shell, and executes the last 3 commands within that new shell.  On Fedora 34, it executes the first 3 commands, opens a new shell, and then waits for input.  I need to exit the new shell and then the last 3 commands are executed within the original shell

Comment: @JohnW I'm not sure if you tried the workaround in my answer before I edited it - but I now found the official option to turn this behavior off and put that in the answer instead. Please let me know how it works out.

Comment: @oguzismail What version of `readline` do you have? I have `8.1-2.fc34` and had to resort to adding a line to `~/.inputrc` to fix this. I'm trying to figure out if what makes it work without changing the `readline` settings for you is in `bash` or `readline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm this in *Fedora 34* / *GNU bash, version 5.1.0(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu*.

This is a new feature in the underlying `readline` library and the feature is enabled by default. Currently, the only way to turn it off is to edit your `~/.inputrc` and add the line:

```
set enable-bracketed-paste off
```

Then, after logging out and in again, you should have the old behavior.